# Pandas - merge/join/vlookup df and delete all rows that get a match

Tags: python, pandas, join

I am trying to reference a list of expired orders from one spreadsheet(df name = data2), and vlookup them on the new orders spreadsheet (df name = data) to delete all the rows that contain expired orders. Then return a new spreadsheet(df name = results).

I am having trouble trying to mimic  what I do in excel vloookup/sort/delete in pandas. Please view psuedo code/steps as code:

1. Import simple.xls as dataframe called 'data'
2. Import wo.xlsm, sheet
       name "T" as dataframe called 'data2'
3. Do a vlookup , using Column
       "A" in the "data" to be used to as the values to be
       matched with any of the same values in Column "A" of "data2" (there both just Order Id's)
4. For all values that exist inside Column A in 'data2'
       and also exist in Column "A" of the 'data',group ( if necessary) and delete the
       entire row(there is 26 columns) for each matched Order ID found in Column A of both datasets. To reiterate, deleting the entire row for the matches found in the 'data' file. Save the smaller dataset as results.

---

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_excel("ors_simple.xlsx", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
    dtype=object)
    data2 = pd.read_excel("wos.xlsm", sheet_name = "T")
    results = data.merge(data2,on='Work_Order')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('vlookuped.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    results.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Which `DataFrame` contains values that you want to be dropped? `data` or `data2`? And do you need to keep the `columns` from the `lookup`-table or do you just want to use it to filter your orders?

Answer (score 6):

I re-read your question and think I undertand it correctly. You want to find out if any order in `new_orders` (you call it `data`) have expired using `expired_orders` (you call it `data2`).

If you rephrase your question what you want to do is: 1) *find out if a value in a column in a `DataFrame` is in a column in another `DataFrame`* and then 2) *drop the rows where the value exists in both*.

---

Using `pd.merge` is one way to do this. But since you want to use `expired_orders` to filter `new_orders`, `pd.merge` seems a bit overkill.

Pandas actually has a method for doing this sort of thing and it's called `isin()` so let's use that! This method allows you to check if a value in one `column` exists in another `column`.

```
df_1['column_name'].isin(df_2['column_name'])
```

`isin()` returns a `Series` of True/False values that you can apply to filter your DataFrame by using it as a mask: `df[bool_mask]`.

So how do you use this in your situation?

```
is_expired = new_orders['order_column'].isin(expired_orders['order_column'])
results = new_orders[~is_expired].copy() # Use copy to avoid SettingWithCopyError.
```

`~`is equal to not - so `~is_expired` means that the order wasn't expired.